# Problem with desktop paring

Tags: display, desktop

I have a laptop that I use as a fix PC. I wired it with a cable. When I turn on my PC from standby, on the desktop I only see the mouse, the rest is black, but on the desktop of the laptop it's all normal. Could you help me to resolve this problem:)

Comment: please provide a lot more information. Are you trying to use an external monitor? What kind of cable are you using (from what type of port to what port). Also a screenshot might help us too. If you open Terminal app and type `xrandr --listmonitors` also send the output of that command.